# Will I still get notifications from Stack Overflow if I don’t have the app but have the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, mobile-app

As in, all I care about from the SO mobile app are the notifications. Can I still get those notifications from the SE mobile app?

Comment: The SE app is for all sites, SO being just one of them.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, yes you can. The SE mobile app will happily provide you with notifications from across the network.